Amount of partitions in relation to amount of brokers and amount of consumers
Let's say I have a Kafka cluster with 3 brokers. If I create
a topic with 1, 2 or 3 partitions it makes sense. What about
a topic with more than 3 partitions? Is there ever a point in
doing that considering that one or more brokers will have more
than one partition of this topic and they can't be read at the
same time any way, so what is the point of creating topics with
more than the amount of brokers in a cluster? Is it just future
proofing in case we add more brokers or is there some other
reason to do this?
What about a topic with more partitions than consumers simultaneously
reading from it? Is there any point to have more partitions than consumers
in this case?

The number of partitions in a topic should ideally be equal to or greater than the maximum number of consumers that will be reading from it simultaneously. This ensures that each consumer can process data from a dedicated partition, maximizing parallelism and throughput. if you have more consomer than partition, they will not consume in parallel.
If you have more partitions than consumers, not all partitions will be actively consumed.
Having more partition allows you to anticipate future developments. But this results in the use of additional resources that are not fully used.
Edit : I agree with OneCricketeer

Having more partitions than consumers is fine


Having more partitions than consumers is fine. At least one consumer will be actively consuming multiple partitions

I know that it's fine in the sense that nothing will break and we won't lose data. But the question is - is there any point in having more partitions than consumers since the whole idea of partitions is parallelization and 3 consumers, for example, can't read simultaneously from 4 partitions.

@bertold You should have et least as much partitions as your max consumer number's. Except this, no you don't need to have more

Creating a Kafka topic with more partitions than there are brokers in the cluster can be a strategic decision for several reasons, even if it might seem counterintuitive at first glance. Let's explore the implications of having more partitions than brokers and more partitions than consumers.
**1. More Partitions than Brokers
When you create a topic with more partitions than the number of brokers:**
Load Distribution: While it's true that each partition can only be assigned to one broker at a time, having more partitions than brokers allows for better load distribution. If your topic has more partitions, when you add more brokers in the future, Kafka can rebalance those partitions across the additional brokers, which improves scalability.
Parallel Processing: During peak loads, having more partitions allows multiple consumers to read from different partitions simultaneously. This can improve throughput, as the workload can be spread across more consumers, even if not all partitions are currently being utilized.
Increased Throughput: More partitions can lead to increased throughput because they allow for higher parallelism in message processing. Different consumers in the same consumer group can read from different partitions, effectively increasing the number of concurrent reads.

More Partitions than Consumers

When you have a topic with more partitions than consumers:
Future Scalability: Having more partitions than consumers allows for future scalability. If you decide to add more consumers later, they can immediately start consuming from the additional partitions without needing to change the topic configuration.
Load Balancing: If a consumer goes down, the partitions it was consuming from can be reassigned to other consumers. If there are more partitions than consumers, this reallocation can happen without losing the ability to read from all partitions.
Reduced Latency: In scenarios where you have bursty loads or variable traffic patterns, having more partitions than consumers can help in reducing latency, as new consumers can be added on-demand to handle increased load.
3. Best Practices
Here are some best practices to consider:
Partition Count: A common recommendation is to start with a number of partitions equal to or greater than the number of brokers, and then increase the count as needed based on throughput requirements and consumer scaling.
Consumer Count: Ideally, you want to have a number of consumers that matches or exceeds the number of partitions for maximum efficiency. However, if you anticipate growth, it can be beneficial to have more partitions than consumers.
Conclusion
Creating a Kafka topic with more partitions than brokers or consumers can be beneficial for future-proofing and allows for better load balancing and throughput optimization. It prepares your Kafka setup for growth and helps ensure that you can scale your consumers without needing to reconfigure your topics.
In summary, while having more partitions than brokers may not provide immediate benefits, it allows for future expansion and improved performance as your workload increases. Similarly, having more partitions than consumers can facilitate better scalability and load distribution.
